# Is a good idea during the process of upload an images create a thumbs?

Tags: image, upload, ruby-on-rails-3.1, paperclip, thumbnails

I am wondering about the best way, how to save & display thumbs of uploaded images. I have a photo gallery and when I upload an image, so I save the image in its original size, thumb1, thumb2 and thumb3. The problem is, that the process of upload takes a lot o time, because are saving 4 images.

I would like to ask what - is better to do that with this way, that I do now (I mean upload an images and then created 3 other thumbs) or upload only the original size of an images and in the view of app just with using CSS manually set the width and size of the thumb an image?

What way do you prefer?
My app is running on Rails 3.1, heroku, for upload uses paperclip and amazon service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have similar feature on our CMS (.NET based). Users upload images and a handler creates thumbnails on demands in desired resolution. There is also disk caching mechanism to ensure some extra performance. It works well for our case.

In your case, I would never use CSS resizing which is a bad idea IMO.

Answer (score 1):

On file upload you should create thumbnail(s) of the image. Ideally you would create a thumbnail for each resolution you display it at.
I wouldn't even resize an image by one pixel width in css. When you resize an image in CSS it is always fully downloaded.
There are many freely available image resizers/thumbnailing scripts. Many of them built into uploaders.
If you're displaying multiple images then you will have a performance bottleneck if they aren't resized, this will annoy your visitors and more importantly chew up server resources.

An example.
A 1000 x 1000 pixel image is 1 million pixels.
saving a resized copy at 100 x 100 on upload and serving that to the user is 10,000 pixels
99% less!!!

If you are totally averse to thumbnail generation I'd recommend looking into caching and compression for sending data to the client and letting them store some locally.